# How can I create an MD5 field using Laravel Migration script?

Tags: mysql, laravel, migration

I need to create a password field. I couldn't find anything similar in Laravel Migration document.

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

There is no `md5` datatype in Databases. Make a `varchar` field for password. And put your `md5` encrypted data in there.

Comment: That seems okay for now.